# Python take a screenshot of specific part of window by mouse drag

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, screenshot, pyautogui

I am now trying to make a python3 program that can simple take a screenshot by dragging mouse. Only method I could find was take a whole screen or give image as input and drag in that image file. I have no idea how to make it so if anyone has any idea, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the co-ordinates of when the mouse first pressed down and after the drag, get the coordinates of which it was released. Using those coordinates, get the region to take a screenshot.